# Cesium GLSL edge detection get the result coordinates of edges

Tags: glsl, edge-detection, cesiumjs

We're using Cesium EdgeDetection fragment shader (GLSL) to detect edges of the 3Dtiles or terrain. Can we get the edge coordinates results from the GLSL context into Cesium context, so that we could implement further processes based on these edge coordinates in JavaScript?

The official EdgeDetection fragment shader in Cesium library:

`packages/engine/Source/Shaders/PostProcessStages/EdgeDetection.glsl`

And the example is as follow,

[image]